# Wrapped line of verbatim text get re-numbered

Tags: context, verbatim, wrap

In ConTeXt, I followed the [example](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Verbatim_text#Line_numbering) on the official wiki of inputting verbatim text.
The screenshot there shows, the long line, when it is wrapped, is correctly refrained from being numbered twice.
However, when I run the same code, the long line is incorrectly renumbered.
Why is that?

```
\defineframedtext
  [framedcode]
  [strut=yes,
   offset=2mm,
   width=7cm,
   align=right]

\definetyping[code][numbering=line,
                    bodyfont=small,
                    before={\startframedcode},
                    after={\stopframedcode}]

\starttext
\startcode
This is the first line
This is a rather long line that is wrapped, so look how the line numbering is done
Another line

Last line after an empty line
\stopcode
\stoptext
```

[image: test wrapped lines]

Comment: Maybe you should ask on ConTeXt mailing list. My guess is something changed in the code, somewhere before 2018 (I get the same output as you with both ConTeXt online and TeXlive 2018).

Comment: Also before May 2017 (which is my TeX Live 2017 version of ConTeXt that also reproduces the problem).

Comment: Okay, I will ask on the mailing list. But still is there any way at this moment to avoid the renumbering?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the question, but rather an answer to your comment asking for a workaround:

> Okay, I will ask on the mailing list. But still is there any way at this moment to avoid the renumbering?

Not recommending to use this even as a workaround but perhaps something similar?

```
\defineframedtext
  [framedcode]
  [strut=yes,
   offset=2mm,
   width=7cm,
   align=right]


\def\startlinenb{%
    \definenumber[line]%
    \EveryLine{\incrementnumber[line]\inmargin{\ttx\getnumber[line]}}%
}

\def\stoplinenb{%
    \resetnumber[line]%
    \EveryLine{}%
}
\definetyping[code][bodyfont=small,
                    before={\startframedcode\startlinenb},
                    after={\stoplinenb\stopframedcode}]


\starttext
\startcode
This is the first line
This is a rather long line that is wrapped, so look how the line numbering is done
Another line

Last line after an empty line
\stopcode
And some text without line numbering.
\stoptext
```

The result is something like this:
[image]

Do bear in mind that this could be and probably is a terrible solution (I just started learning ConTeXt...), but it does kind-of work.

Comment: I think your solution is not so bad actually :)